# Not getting the :id of element using AutoComplete jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

guys I m using the jquery Autocomplete to my rails 3.1 application to getting the countries I want that it should when i type the country initials it gives me the name of country and when i submit my form it sends the :id of that element in params i have done all the things mentions but still not getting the id as params
my code is

```
<%= form_for(@company_admin ,:url => admins_path) do |f| %>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 #all fields for company admin

          <%= f.fields_for :company do |company| %>
              #all fields for company
              .
              .

              <%= label_tag :Country %>
              <%= autocomplete_field_tag :country ,"" ,  autocomplete_country_name_admins_path ,:element_id=>"#country_id",:size => 75,:class => "field" %>
              </tr>
          <%end %>

          <%= f.submit 'Create' %> 


  <%end  %>
```

and i m getting params like

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", "country"=>"india", "company_admin"=>{"company_attributes"=>{"address"=>"gt road", "category"=>"IT", "company_name"=>"google", "sub_domain"=>"classfieldidsub_domain", "telephone_number"=>"(+111) 111-111-1111"}, "gender"=>"Mr.", "last_name"=>"pqr", "email"=>"abv@gmail.com", "first_name"=>"abc"}, "authenticity_token"=>"X6bgRzJ5ydXJCyZ8+GhN57Z+O2K9gL1dsV15YQaXa84=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

ie in `params[:country]` i m getting "india"
i want it should give the :id of "india"

so guys plaease help me to figure this out thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm having the same problem and none of the answers from this or related questions are working.  Would love to know how you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a hidden field. That's where autocomplete is going to insert your id value.
You then read it from params hash in your controller

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :country_id, :id => "my_country_id" %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :country ,  autocomplete_country_name_admins_path ,:element_id=>"#my_country_id",:size => 75,:class => "field" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change `:element_id=>"#country_id"`  with `:element_id=>"#id"`

```
      <%= f.fields_for :company do |company| %>
          ....
          <%= f.label :Country %>
          <%= f.autocomplete_field :country ,  autocomplete_country_name_admins_path ,:element_id=>"#id",:size => 75,:class => "field" %>
          </tr>
      <%end %>
```

also i encourage you to user form helpers method instead of form helper tag if they are available :)

--Updates adding some source from rails3-jquery-autocomplete

```
  # Returns an input tag of the "text" type tailored for accessing a specified attribute (identified by +method+) and
  # that is populated with jQuery's autocomplete plugin.
  #
  # ==== Examples
  #   autocomplete_field(:post, :title, author_autocomplete_path, :size => 20)
  #   # => <input type="text" id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="20" value="#{@post.title}"  data-autocomplete="author/autocomplete"/>
  #
  def autocomplete_field(object_name, method, source, options ={})
    options["data-autocomplete"] = source
    text_field(object_name, method, rewrite_autocomplete_option(options))
  end

#
# Method used to rename the autocomplete key to a more standard
# data-autocomplete key
#
private

def rewrite_autocomplete_option(options)
  options["data-update-elements"] = JSON.generate(options.delete :update_elements) if  options[:update_elements]
  options["data-id-element"] = options.delete :id_element if options[:id_element]
  options
end
```

it seems that `autocomplete_field` generate `:element_id` as html5 `element data attribute` for text filed 
and again from gems source

```
:extra_data 
By default, your search will only return the required columns from the database needed to populate your form, namely id and the column you are searching (name, in the above example).
```

looks like they  will return id by sending message to object with by given element_id.

Comment: hey Naveed thanks for the answer but after change the code as u suggest to me i m still getting not getting the :id

Comment: can you inspect autocomplete text filed and seegenerated htlm. is there "data-id-element" here? what is its value?, and what is your browser did it support html5?

Comment: Naveed now i m using form helper as u suggested  and my generated html is <input class="field ui-autocomplete-input" data-autocomplete="/admins/autocomplete_country_name" element_id="#id" id="company_admin_company_attributes_country" name="company_admin[company_attributes][country]" size="75" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">

Comment: hmm, "element_id" was not excepted,it should be "data-id-element" . may be its causing issue.which gem you are using?  https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.    this one?

Comment: ya its "rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the code above, try that. the code i was going to have you use wasn't form as it should be with a form_for helper.

After you make the autocomplete code with the form_for helper it should return the params.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide hidden field with some id, so that selected element's id will get populated in that hidden field. For example:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :country_id, id: 'my_country_id' %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :country, autocomplete_country_name_admins_path ,id_element: '#my_country_id', size: 75, class: 'field' %>
```

For those who want to use with Form_tag:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :country_id, '', id: 'my_country_id' %>
<%= autocomplete_field_tag :country, autocomplete_country_name_admins_path ,id_element: '#my_country_id', size: 75, class: 'field' %>
```

For detailed description and reference,
Please visit: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/0.6.2